# Memory leaks not happening in a Virtual machine but pops up when ran natively

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, virtual-machine

I develop with Delphi 2010 in a VM, the app runs well inside the VM in any ways within the ide, alone with or without Eurekalog using mainly DevExpress grids and AidAim SQLMemtables.
When the same App is ran on the host (ie directly on windows) the eurekalog finds memory leaks on the SQLMemtable dataset component and sometimes but often enough to make it impossible to release it crashes on a simple Dataset.refresh. It is very hard to debug because in the debug environemnt it works.
Anyone would have any idea what is going on, I am at loss of ideas here
Thank you for your help
Regards
Philippe Watel

Comment: What you must identify is the differences. Check debug/release mode, external files, OS, anything.

Comment: A good memory manager will tell you where the leaked memory was allocated. Full FastMM does this.

Comment: Try to explain a bit more about your app architecture - are you using threads? Are you doing intensive memory allocations and deallocations within tight loops, etc. Are there significant differences between the host machine and the VM in terms of resources, speed, etc? What else is running on the host machine vs the VM? Usually leaks that show in one environment and not in another have to do with timing and resource availability. Aside from David's and Lars's recommendations, you probably should try to focus on these points to zero in on the problem code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your external dependencies (dlls) differ on both machines? Also consider using Delphi's remote debugger and log more details to find out more details about your problem.

Comment: To my knowledge what is needed is there on both machines.

Comment: Are they exactly the same version as well? Or how about using different Windows versions or more threads which make your application or the libraries you use behave different?

Comment: @Philippe Watel you should accept this as a answer if Lars's answer was helpful!!